# php outputting text with keywords highlighted

Tags: php, words

i have a system that outputs a film review, when it is outputted i want the keywords that appear in it from 2 tables - negative and positive to be in a different colour any idea to do this ? The code is below

```
<?php

// Connect to database
mysql_connect("sdd", "sdsd", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("sdsd") or die(mysql_error());

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reviewid']); 

//$query = "select * from review where id = '$id'";
$query = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT filmreview FROM review WHERE id = '$id'"));
$pos = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM positive");
$neg = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM negative");


//Variables 
$review_text = $query['filmreview'];
$good = 0;
$bad = 0; 


// Gets words in to a text array and converts to lower case 
$cnt_r = array_count_values(array_map('mb_strtolower',str_word_count($review_text, 1)));

// Gets the positive words and check for the word in the text  
    while($check = mysql_fetch_assoc($pos)){
       $lower = mb_strtolower($check['word']);
     if(isset($cnt_r[$lower])){
    $good+= $cnt_r[$lower];
    echo $check ['word'];
    echo "<p>"; 
     } 
    }

// Gets the negative words and check for the word in the text 
while($check = mysql_fetch_assoc($neg)){
  $lower = mb_strtolower($check['word']);
 if(isset($cnt_r[$lower])){
    $bad+= $cnt_r[$lower];
        echo $check ['word'];
        echo "<p>";
 }  
} 


// If there are more positive words than negative than the review is positive  
if ($good > $bad)
{
    echo "<p>"; 
    echo "This is a positive review";
    echo "<p>";
}

// If there are more negative words than positive than the review is negative 
else if ($good < $bad)
{
    echo "<p>";
    echo "This is a negative review";
    echo "<p>";
}

// If there are the same amount of positive and negative words than the review is average 
else if ($good == $bad)
{
    echo "<p>";
    echo "This is an average review";
    echo "<p>";
}

//Prints out the number of postive and negative words found 
echo "Good words: " . $good . " and Bad words: " . $bad;
echo "<p>";
echo $query ['filmreview'];
echo "<p>";
echo "This is <font color=\"blue\">blue</font>!"; 



echo "<form method='post' action='welcome.html'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='searchagain' value='Search'>";
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the replies but i cant get any of them to work dont know what im doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just search and find your keywords in the text and then just replace them.
So roughly

```
    if($postivekeyword) {  
       $newpostivekeyword = '<span class="positive">'.$postivekeyword.'</span>';
   }
    if($negativekeyword) {  
      $newnegativekeyword = '<span class="negative">'.$negativekeyword.'</span>';
    }
```

Then just

```
   $new_review_text = str_replace($postivekeyword, $newpostivekeyword, $review_text);
```

Comment: how do i include the colours to this ? as nothing is outputted

Comment: just add the classes to your css

         .negative { color: red; }
         .positive { color: black; }

and of course in the file you need somewhere

        echo $new_review_text;

Comment: are you getting any errors ?
which bit is not working ? the search & replace, the highlighing of the keywords ? the text output ? more info please

Comment: I put in your method correctly but only the review was being out putted with nothing coloured but I have managed to get it to work

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS classes.

In your stylesheet or in a style tag within you page you could create the css classes:

```
p .negative { color: red; }
p .positive { color: black; }
```

Now just add the class to your paragraph and it would apply the styles you want.

```
// If there are more positive words than negative than the review is positive  
if ($good > $bad)
{
    echo '<p class="positive">'; 
    echo 'This is a positive review';
    echo '</p>';
}

// If there are more negative words than positive than the review is negative 
else if ($good < $bad)
{
    echo '<p class="negative">';
    echo 'This is a negative review';
    echo '</p>';
}
```

etc.....

Comment: but i want the words in the text to be coloured not the review type

Comment: If you are just picking words out of a paragraph to color you could use the same priciple, just use a span class that you append to the beginning and end of each word instead of a class for the whole paragraph.

Answer (score -1):

1. try to read a query's response right after you sent it. This way you avoid having the results of multiple queries clog your memory
2. `$cnt_r = array_count_values(array_map('mb_strtolower',str_word_count($review_text, 1)));` seems to be a fraked up version of `$cnt_r = str_word_count(mb_strtolower($review_text), 2);`
3. str_word_count is not multibyte safe. In [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) I've used `preg_match_all('#[\w\pL]+#u', $review_text, $matches);` as the base of a UTF-8 version of str_word_count().
4. give [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) a closer look
5. give your variables some identifying names
6. always esacape your output properly - htmlspecialchars() is there to be used!
7. It is 2012 - we do not ever use the `<font>` tag! use CSS instead!

---

```
<?php
$query = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT filmreview FROM review WHERE id = '$id'"));
$review_text = $query['filmreview'];

// Gets words in to a text array and converts to lower case 
$review_words = array_count_values(array_map('mb_strtolower',str_word_count($review_text, 1)));

$positive_words = array();
$negative_words = array();
$positive_words_count = 0;
$negative_words_count = 0;

// Gets the positive words and check for the word in the text  
$res = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM positive");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    // why isn't this already stored lower-case in database?
    $_word = mb_strtolower($row['word']);
    if (isset($review_words[$_word])){
        $positive_words_count += $review_words[$_word];
        $positive_words[] = $_word;
    } 
}

// Gets the negative words and check for the word in the text 
$res = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM negative");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    // why isn't this already stored lower-case in database?
    $_word = mb_strtolower($row['word']);
    if (isset($review_words[$_word])){
        $negative_words_count += $review_words[$_word];
        $negative_words[] = $_word;
    }  
}

if ($positive_words_count > $negative_words_count) {
    // If there are more positive words than negative than the review is positive  
    echo "<p>This is a positive review<p>";
} elseif ($positive_words_count < $negative_words_count) {
    // If there are more negative words than positive than the review is negative 
    echo "<p>This is a negative review<p>";
} else {
    // If there are the same amount of positive and negative words than the review is average 
    echo "<p>This is an average review<p>";
}

// highlight positive/negative words
$review_text = htmlspecialchars($review_text);
$pattern = '#\b(' . join('|', $positive_words) . ')\b#i';
$review_text = preg_replace($pattern, "<span class=\"positive\"\\1</span>", $review_text);
$pattern = '#\b(' . join('|', $negative_words) . ')\b#i';
$review_text = preg_replace($pattern, "<span class=\"negative\"\\1</span>", $review_text);

//Prints out the number of postive and negative words found 
echo "Good words: " . $positive_words_count . " and Bad words: " . $negative_words_count;
echo "<p>" . $review_text . "<p>";
echo "This is <font color=\"blue\">blue</font>!";
```

and somewhere in your CSS define what `span.negative` and `span.positive` should look like.

Comment: how do i define the css i have never used it before

Comment: goole for "introduction to css" and you'll find bunch of useful things like http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Guide/Style

Comment: hi following from what you said here how can i apply the preg_match so that it identifies lowercase and capital ?